# Stream of elements between two objects?

Tags: java, queue, java-stream

I have an own implemented Queue. The Queue has two nodes, the front and end.
Now I want to implement a size method with a Stream.
I want to make a Stream between the two nodes and return the size of the Stream.

But at this point, I don't know how to make a Stream of all nodes between two nodes.

The nodes have a variable of the type Node pointing to the next in queue, this variable is null for the last node.

I already tried to make a Stream of Node.getNext and filter out the elements of the Stream which are null.

```java
public class Node<T> {

    private Node<T> next;
    private T element;

    public Node(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getElement() {
        return element;
    }

}

public class Queue<T> { 

   private Node<T> front;
   private Node<T> back;

   public int size() {
           // This works but I want to use Stream
           /*
           int i = 0;
           Node<T> n = front;
           while (n.getNext() != null) {
               i++;
               n = n.getNext();
           }
           i++;
           return i;
           */
           return (int) Stream.iterate(
                   front, Node::getNext)
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                   .count();
    }

}
```

I expect the number 3, but the actual result is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Stream$1.tryAdvance(Stream.java:1226)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:326)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$5.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:257)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$5.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.count(ReferencePipeline.java:605)
    at Queue.size(Queue.java:46)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Comment: Seems like you're accessing an infinite stream there. Possibly ending up with a `null ` value from `getNext`

Comment: Yes, that's right, but how do I end the Stream if `getNext` returns `null`?

Comment: If you're creating your own Queue implementation, it might be worth referencing http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was close.

But you need to use other version of `iterate`.

```
Stream.iterate(front, x -> x != null, Node::getNext)
      .count()
```

Comment: The problem is not that the seed is null. I use IntelliJ and the call of .count() has the warning "Non-short-circuit operation consumes the infinite stream.".

Comment: Yes. I realized that. Fixed my solution.

Comment: The original code, using the two-arg version, would also work, if the OP did not use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`, but `takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)`, but that’s equivalent to the more concise `Stream.iterate(front, Objects::nonNull, Node::getNext)`…